# Why doesn't "ls -al *.swp" show all files with .swp extension in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

Directory content

```
rtetteh@PW02R9F3:~/Projects$ ls -al
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  5 rtetteh rtetteh  4096 Oct 27 13:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 rtetteh rtetteh  4096 Oct 27 13:45 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 rtetteh rtetteh 12288 Sep 30 15:19 .ThreadTest.cpp.swp
drwxr-xr-x  2 rtetteh rtetteh  4096 Oct 27 13:45 .recycleBin
-rw-r--r--  1 rtetteh rtetteh   953 Oct 27 13:44 ThreadTest.cpp
-rwxr-xr-x  1 rtetteh rtetteh 24984 Sep 30 15:14 ThreadTest_exe
drwxr-xr-x  2 rtetteh rtetteh  4096 Aug 17 18:26 hello
drwxr-xr-x  6 rtetteh rtetteh  4096 Oct 21 15:12 python-account-manager
-rwxr-xr-x  1 rtetteh rtetteh   168 Aug 19 20:23 test_pos_param.sh
```

Test 1

```
rtetteh@PW02R9F3:~/Projects$ ls -al *.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rtetteh rtetteh 168 Aug 19 20:23 test_pos_param.sh
```

Test 2

```
rtetteh@PW02R9F3:~/Projects$ ls -al *.swp
ls: cannot access '*.swp': No such file or directory
```

Why does Test 1 work and not Test 2.
How do I get Test 2 to work i.e show files with .swp extension

Comment: Hidden files could be hidden from * glob. Some info here: https://bertvv.github.io/notes-to-self/2021/09/21/file-globbing-and-hidden-files/

Comment: The glob (replacing `*.swp` with a list of matching files on the command line) is done by the shell before `ls` starts, so how you configure `ls` (f/e, whether you set `-a`) can't change its results. The shell doesn't know what `-a` means; only `ls` does.

Comment: a few alternatives: `ls -al .*.swp *.swp` or `ls -al | grep '\.swp'` or `find . -name "*.swp" -exec ls -al {} \;`

Comment: You can also set `shopt -s dotglob`.

Comment: You might want to add an answer to this question, otherwise it has little value for future readers.

Comment: Hi all please add answer to this question as opposed to comments...thanks and  much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your incorrect assumption is that **asterisk** expands to include "**.**" at the start of the string.  Shell defaults don't make that match in regexp.

You need to specifically specify "**.*.swp**" in order to make the correct expansion.  That also doesn't need the -a switch for ls, because you specified the "**.**" prefix.